# Dual-Boot Ubuntu on Mac Book Air (2019)

Tags: dual-boot, mac, usb-installation

I'm currently trying to dual boot my Mac Book Air (2019, macOS Catalina) with Ubuntu, but after some research I'm not sure if this is even possible, since 2018 Apple started to use this T2 protection.
Right now I've got a bootable USB with the latest Ubuntu ISO but when I'm trying to boot, my options are *Ubuntu* or *Ubuntu (some grafics)* (and some others for manufacturers) which both lead to some white writings on a black screen updating me about my usb and its content. But Linux is not booting. Thus, my questions are: Is it possible at all without manual programming to dual boot? If yes, why is my USB not booting?

Thanks for some help,
Sebastian

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/